# Data table search comes to the first page after refresh instead of current

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap data table for my records. But when I am on the 2nd page of the table and if I refreshed the page it redirects me to the 1st page of the table instead of the 2nd page any idea how to solve this issue.

```
$("#dataTablesFull, #dataTablesFull2, #dataTablesFull3, #dataTablesFull4").dataTable( {
                    "pageLength": <?php echo getConfigValue("table_records"); ?>,
                    "dom": '<"top"f>rt<"bottom"><"row dt-margin"<"col-md-6"i><"col-md-6"p><"col-md-12"B>><"clear">',
                    "buttons":  [ 'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print' ],
                    "oLanguage": {
                        "sSearch": "<i class='fa fa-search text-gray dTsearch'></i>",
                        "sEmptyTable": "<?php _e('No entries to show'); ?>",
                        "sZeroRecords": "<?php _e('Nothing found'); ?>",
                        "sInfo": "<?php _e('Showing'); ?> _START_ <?php _e('to'); ?> _END_ <?php _e('of'); ?> _TOTAL_ <?php _e('entries'); ?>",
                        "sInfoEmpty": "",
                        "oPaginate": {
                            "sNext": "<?php _e('Next'); ?>",
                            "sPrevious": "<?php _e('Previous'); ?>",
                            "sFirst": "<?php _e('First Page'); ?>",
                            "sLast": "<?php _e('Last Page'); ?>"
                        }
                    },
                    "columnDefs": [ { "orderable": false, "targets": -1 } ] }
                );
                $("#dataTablesFullNoOrder, #dataTablesFullNoOrder2").dataTable( {
                    "order": [],
                    "pageLength": <?php echo getConfigValue("table_records"); ?>,
                    "dom": '<"top"f>rt<"bottom"><"row dt-margin"<"col-md-6"i><"col-md-6"p><"col-md-12"B>><"clear">',
                    "buttons":  [ 'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print' ],
                    "oLanguage": {
                        "sSearch": "<i class='fa fa-search text-gray dTsearch'></i>",
                        "sEmptyTable": "<?php _e('No entries to show'); ?>",
                        "sZeroRecords": "<?php _e('Nothing found'); ?>",
                        "sInfo": "<?php _e('Showing'); ?> _START_ <?php _e('to'); ?> _END_ <?php _e('of'); ?> _TOTAL_ <?php _e('entries'); ?>",
                        "sInfoEmpty": "",
                        "oPaginate": {
                            "sNext": "<?php _e('Next'); ?>",
                            "sPrevious": "<?php _e('Previous'); ?>",
                            "sFirst": "<?php _e('First Page'); ?>",
                            "sLast": "<?php _e('Last Page'); ?>"
                        }
                    },
                    "columnDefs": [ { "orderable": false, "targets": -1 } ] }
                );
                $("#dataTablesFullDesc, #dataTablesFullDesc2").dataTable( {
                    "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
                    "pageLength": <?php echo getConfigValue("table_records"); ?>,
                    "dom": '<"top"f>rt<"bottom"><"row dt-margin"<"col-md-6"i><"col-md-6"p><"col-md-12"B>><"clear">',
                    "buttons":  [ 'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print' ],
                    "oLanguage": {
                        "sSearch": "<i class='fa fa-search text-gray dTsearch'></i>",
                        "sEmptyTable": "<?php _e('No entries to show'); ?>",
                        "sZeroRecords": "<?php _e('Nothing found'); ?>",
                        "sInfo": "<?php _e('Showing'); ?> _START_ <?php _e('to'); ?> _END_ <?php _e('of'); ?> _TOTAL_ <?php _e('entries'); ?>",
                        "sInfoEmpty": "",
                        "oPaginate": {
                            "sNext": "<?php _e('Next'); ?>",
                            "sPrevious": "<?php _e('Previous'); ?>",
                            "sFirst": "<?php _e('First Page'); ?>",
                            "sLast": "<?php _e('Last Page'); ?>"
                        }
                    },
                    "columnDefs": [ { "orderable": false, "targets": -1 } ] }
                );

                $("a[data-tab-destination]").on('click', function() {
                    var tab = $(this).attr('data-tab-destination');
                    $("#"+tab).click();
                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want the statesave feature. It saves the state of the table including pagination in the cookies so that upon returning to the page or refreshing the page it will maintain the state it was in.

[datatable state save](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/state_save.html)

```
$(document).ready(function() {$('#example').DataTable( {stateSave: true} );} );
```

Comment: Thank you.. For resolving this issue

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is set a URL hash to the current tab and then on refresh, call the click function of that tab. (You could also use something like sessions to do this if you don't like having a hash in the URL).  What I like about the hash option is bookmarking will work.

```
$("a[data-tab-destination]").on('click', function() {
   var tab = $(this).attr('data-tab-destination');
   window.location.hash = '#' + encodeURIComponent(tab);
   $("#"+tab).click();
});

if(window.loaction.hash) {
  var tag = decodeURIComponent(window.location.hash.substring(1));
  $("a[data-tab-destination]").click();
}
```